# Iterate Collection on jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report that is simple, it has a few string paramters that receive all the data that i need. The strings are like this "1;2;3", "bob;john;mary". And i just need to show the data in rows. And it is working on jaspersoft. BUT not on jasperserver, when i run the report on jaspersoft server, it doesnt show the data.

I use .split(";") on the strings and cast it to arraylist  and use it as datasource for my subreports. It is ugly but works, at least on jaspersoft. But it just doesnt on jasperserver.

The data comes from a angular project, and is filled by the user. I dont have this data on the DB.

I think its a problem on the way im using the datasource on the subreports but im not sure. Im new to jaspersoft. If this is not the way i should be doing this, pls say so, any help is appreciated

Here is my report code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.13.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="OcorrenciasBancarias" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8fbddf4a-554c-4f04-9941-b9e16c98b10d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="RK ERP Devel"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://192.168.0.205:11001/jasperserver/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/reports/telas/quitacao_multiplas_contas/arquivo_retorno/ocorrenciasBancarias_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/telas/quitacao_multiplas_contas/arquivo_retorno/ocorrenciasBancarias"/>
    <parameter name="CLIENTE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="DOCUMENTO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NOSSONUMERO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="VALOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="VENCIMENTO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="OCORRENCIA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CLIENTELIST" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{CLIENTE}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DOCUMENTOLIST" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{DOCUMENTO}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="NOSSONUMEROLIST" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{NOSSONUMERO}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="VALORLIST" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{VALOR}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="VENCIMENTOLIST" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{VENCIMENTO}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="OCORRENCIALIST" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{OCORRENCIA}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="379" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="a29fce94-a139-4d14-b782-9fe95ed43793">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="HH:mm">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="432" y="0" width="50" height="20" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="22d51de7-fdb2-4681-a3d4-bc3ba4a4cc65">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="20" width="554" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="58d13352-4653-4587-827c-ea222229bbbe">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="20" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="7199097a-7296-410a-91f4-250495caab85">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                        <pen lineColor="#9FEDE5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="552" height="20" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="592cfe50-8cc4-473d-bac5-93c67922aedd">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[INFO FROM PARAMETERS]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </frame>
            </frame>
            <textField evaluationTime="Master">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="442" y="0" width="112" height="20" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="921629e5-89b3-4d65-886d-fe20c21fa84b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Página "+$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+" de "+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="13" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#595959" uuid="34831667-1d80-4cae-a91d-d6651c1cf3f4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="32" height="14" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="549ff20c-f7e6-46b8-b431-d361f478c4a5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="4a6727e1-e6e7-4a70-8291-1a81b0a10118"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cliente]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="60" height="14" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="835a1ff7-8ed8-4a88-b5f1-00cd6677957c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="88aaba7a-4029-4a82-b1c2-ee8e93b1feb2"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Documento]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="70" height="14" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="dd5bfaf9-d080-4499-86f2-a7e0e4d3b492">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="5c2a2b79-9bac-4851-b7b3-c7642b0976ad"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nosso Número]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="70" height="14" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="33fb80ff-5f98-4c6f-ae62-1695b0b08490">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d4028cee-3416-4e73-8c8d-56b544671f27"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="350" y="0" width="60" height="14" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="056f347b-d9a2-49ee-8674-8d31e9b07ea8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="8e8f8fed-a90c-4c5b-b2cc-d0ad1c49dc1a"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Vencimento]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="420" y="0" width="134" height="14" forecolor="#27272F" uuid="af29b7ba-2bc2-45be-a78a-f70bda792540">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="8e8f8fed-a90c-4c5b-b2cc-d0ad1c49dc1a"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ocorrência]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="914c099d-14bb-48a7-a696-73973de7093b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{CLIENTELIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["SUBREPORT.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="924b44a1-81c6-4634-929d-e0ece1e11e2a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{DOCUMENTOLIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["SUBREPORT_VALOR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="c957a547-8e5f-4985-83fd-cc7eebbe8568"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{NOSSONUMEROLIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["SUBREPORT_NUMERO.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="735a18c3-59ff-425f-9752-4a54a29b7ccf">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{VALORLIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["SUBREPORT_VALOR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="350" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="417264e1-2694-462b-8cdc-a2768c3ef18c"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{VENCIMENTOLIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["SUBREPORT_VALOR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="420" y="0" width="135" height="30" uuid="5b686650-452c-4286-8513-163fa164f3ce">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{OCORRENCIALIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["SUBREPORT_OCORRENCIA.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I don't get how this can work `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{VENCIMENTOLIST})`. You should provide a collection of beans and you are providing a collection of Strings. What is the name of the fields ($F) in the subreports?

Comment: The field name is _THIS. $F{_THIS}. I dont know how it works.

Comment: In server can you see the main report parts? In Studio, which data adapter are you using? "One empty record"?

Comment: Yes, i can see the main report parts in server. Im currently using my data base as data adapter, i tried with the one empty record and it didnt show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you have already done. But uses a single subreport.

```
$P{numbers}: 1;2;3
$P{names}: a;b;c
$P{numbersList}: Arrays.asList($P{numbers}.split(";"))
$P{namesList}: Arrays.asList($P{names}.split(";"))

$P{recordsList}: java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, $P{numbersList}.size()).mapToObj( i -> new String[]{(String)$P{numbersList}.get(i), (String)$P{namesList}.get(i)} ).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList())
```

The above code takes de 1st element of each list and  puts in a single array. Then, takes de 2nd element of each list and so on. In the end you have this:

```
List[ [1, a], [2, b], [3, c] ]
```

When calling the subreport, you pass this datasource:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.ListOfArrayDataSource( 
    $P{recordsList},
    new String[]{"number", "name"}
)
```

Obviously, in the subreport you must have the fields `number` and `name`.

This worked for me in Jaspersoft Studio.

Main.jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.14.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.14.0-2ab0d8625be255bf609c78e1181801213e51db8f  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Main" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="acfc3351-2262-463e-ae8a-dd475abdd1bc">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="numbers" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1;2;3;4;5;6"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="names" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["a;b;c;d;e;f"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="numbersList" class="java.util.List" nestedType="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{numbers}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="namesList" class="java.util.List" nestedType="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{names}.split(";"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="recordsList" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, $P{numbersList}.size()).mapToObj( i -> new String[]{(String)$P{numbersList}.get(i), (String)$P{namesList}.get(i)} ).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList())]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="30">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30" uuid="3bde936c-9702-404e-9932-68d37a915600"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{numbersList}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30" uuid="213c86ad-069a-4bdd-9840-cb71559fa265"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{namesList}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30" uuid="8049f4ff-e490-4a1c-8c85-71be6335ba69"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.ListOfArrayDataSource( $P{recordsList}, new String[]{"number", "name"} )]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Sub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Sub.jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.14.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.14.0-2ab0d8625be255bf609c78e1181801213e51db8f  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sub" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f06a30d4-cc6b-4ca5-a42f-3dcf791be297">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="NO_DATA_ADAPTER"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30" uuid="3705eb7a-891e-4118-bcad-abae96e78171">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="4faf3089-5386-4350-9b8c-6f2f3eac41f7"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[number]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30" uuid="e194e190-bf9a-4f01-8aef-c2799a240199">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cf256fba-83b6-4575-9cc7-487a63cfb77b"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30" uuid="572c825e-3188-4b27-95e1-b24ac2009d6a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="4faf3089-5386-4350-9b8c-6f2f3eac41f7"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30" uuid="f1662cf8-13a8-4d5d-b55a-0901b2aabec3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cf256fba-83b6-4575-9cc7-487a63cfb77b"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: It did work better than my code in jasperstudio but it still didnt work on jasperserver. Im still trying to figure it out why it refuses to work there. But thank you very much.

Comment: My guess is that Jasper server is passing another datasource that is overriding the one you pass.